# how do i put a static block in the left or right column using the rwd theme in magento

Tags: layout, rwd-theme, blocks

How do i put a static block in the left or right column using the rwd theme
in magento?  I can't find any tutorials to about this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the RWD themes `local.xml` layout file

```
[...]
<default>
   <reference name="left">
      <block type="cms/block" name="[a unique name]">
         <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>[the block identifier]</block_id></action>
      </block>
   </reference>
</default>
[...]
```

Some good layout XML resources in case you want to read up

- https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/XML+Layouts+for+Frontend
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-layouts-and-templates-with-magento--cms-21419

Answer (score 1):

the way I did it is by using a widget, first you create the static block and after you go to widgets, create a new instance and when you configure it, you tell it to use the static block, the pages to apear and you can chose wher it will show up.
Hope this helps